# How to change highlighting color in Visual Studio using ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz7vm.jpg]

Where my arrow is pointing I have seen various people who have changed the color of the highlight to blue or cyan or some other color that is easier to see and "pops out" more. I have tried searching on stack overflow and the internet and have been unsuccessful at finding how to change this specific thing rather than changing the entire color of all highlighting text. Basically when you click next to an end brace or beginning it highlights the other one but in my case its grey and I would like it to be blue or something better. How do I do this? Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post the image in this specific post.

I looked through Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors for nearly every option and changed lots of things around, but nothing changed the way it highlights those braces when you click next to one. I was able to successfully change the color it highlights it but the second I release my mouse it changes back to grey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors
  Resharper Brace Outline
  Resharper Matched Brace Items
```

To change whether to display color or outline, go to Resharper Options:

```
Resharper > Environment > Editor > Highlight with [x] color [ ] outline
```

[ReSharper Help/Highlighting Matching Delimiters](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Coding_Assistance__Matching_Delimiters.html)